# Display Average value from ViewModel in View

Tags: c#, html, linq, razor, mvvm

I've developed a ViewModel with the same information of a Model Class, but I've added to the ViewModel a field named AvgAge(Age Average of all the people), I want to display a table in the view with these fields: Name, Lastname and Age of all the people... and above the table I want to display a label with the Age Average of all the people.. I need to declare inside the View the ViewModel as IEnumerable so I can iterate over the list and display the information on the table.. until here everything works great. Now the problem is when I'm trying to show the result of the Age Average, it's only a result.. What do you suggest me??

Method I'm using to display the list of people in the table:

```
  public List<PersonAgeAvg> AvgAge()
        {
            var list = db.People.Select(x => new PersonAgeAvg
            {
                Name = x.Name,
                LastName = x.LastName,
                Age = x.Age               
            }).ToList();
            return list;
        }
```

I know I can get the Age Average with a query like this, but where should I use this query??:

```
 AvgAge = db.People.Select(p => p.Age).Average()
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AlexMusicStore.ViewModel.PersonAgeAvg>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetPersonAgeAvg";
}

<h2>GetPersonAgeAvg</h2>
<p>
 @Html.ActionLink("Create new", "Create")    
</p>
<label>Average Age: </label> 
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Maybe a solution should be to create a ViewModel only with the AgeAverage field but I don't know how to show the AgeAverage field in the view after with the other elements Name, Lastname and Age too... Is possible to show fields from different ViewModels in the same View???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using the Tuple method, this method allows to work with two models or ViewModels or more at the same View...

Controller Action:

```
 public ActionResult GetPersonAgeAvg()
        {
            var avg = ope.AgeAverage();
            IEnumerable<Person> pers = db.People.ToList();
            var tuple = new Tuple<IEnumerable<Person>, PersonAgeAvg>(pers, avg);
            return View(tuple);
        }
```

And int the View:

```
@model Tuple<IEnumerable<AlexMusicStore.Models.Person>,AlexMusicStore.ViewModel.PersonAgeAvg>

<label>Average Age: </label> @Html.DisplayFor(tuple => tuple.Item2.AvgAge)

<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in Model.Item1)
{ 
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your view you can do something like this

```
@ var avAge=Model.People.Select(p => p.Age).Average();
```